# Writing an R package vignette that reads in an example file?

Tags: r, sweave

I'm trying to write a vignette for a package in R. I've been following [a tutorial from Vanderbilt University](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/HowToCreateAnRPackage) as well as [the offical documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf).

I made a `.Rnw` Sweave file and put it into a subdirectory `inst/doc` inside my package. Inside the same subdirectory `inst/doc`, I put a folder `example` containing some example text files. My package has a function `myparser(path)` that I want to demonstrate in the vignette; `myparser(path)` creates several data frames by reading in the text files inside the folder with absolute path name `path`.

Then I checked the package using `R CMD CHECK`, and got this error:

```
* checking running R code from vignettes ...
   ‘mypackage-vignette.Rnw’ using ‘UTF-8’ ... failed
 ERROR
Errors in running code in vignettes:
when running code in ‘mypackage-vignette.Rnw’
  ...
> library(mypackage)
Loading required package: ggplot2

> myparser("/example/")
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/example/': No such file or directory

  When sourcing ‘mypackage-vignette.R’:
Error: cannot open the connection
Execution halted
```

I see my attempt to use a relative pathway to the folder didn't work (probably should have been obvious to me), but I'm still not sure how to fix this situation. I don't want to replace `path` with an absolute pathway to the folder on *my computer*, because then the vignette's code won't be reproducible on other people's computers.

How can I include the example files in the package so that the vignette's code is reproducible? Am I even approaching this problem in the right way?

(Sorry this question isn't itself more reproducible!)

Comment: Have you tried using `system.file` to refer to the file?

Comment: apparently `/example/` is an absolute path; you probably mean `example/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `system.file('doc', 'example', package = 'mypackage')` to refer to that directory, because R will install the package before building vignettes, as you can see when you run `R CMD build mypackage`.